# Installing Mathematica on removable drive

Tags: installation

I have a student license for Mathematica 10.3 and I recently got myself a chromebook (Acer c720) and was wondering if it was possible to install on, say, my SD card. I attempted it once the other night and it didn't quite seem to work, the details of which I will give.

I currently have Lubuntu on the chromebook, and with the current install of Mathematica 10.1 on the internal disk the remaining space on it is <1GB. I am, of course, willing to change the distro if it is somehow required to install on a removable drive. I recently attempted to install it in the following manner: with the setup .sh stored on an external hard drive, and an empty SD Card inserted, I ran the install which successfully created a directory inside the SD Card, but afterwards seemed to do nothing. By this I mean it proceeded to attempt to install but made no progress, and the low CPU usage indicated that there wasn't any installation activity.

In short: has anyone tried installing Mathematica on a removable drive with Linux? Or know if its even possible?

Comment: Perhaps you should also consider contacting wolfram support with your issue. They know the system's requirements better, so they might have a much more definitive answer.

Comment: I actually did send them an email, to which they have yet to respond.

Comment: In the past, at least, the activation key was tied to some unspecified combination of hardware characteristics.

Comment: It's probably not the case but a simple enough thing to overlook: make sure that the SD card isn't write-locked.

Comment: It would seem that single licenses are tied to the `$MathID`,  which is dependent on the machine configuration (understandably in an undisclosed way).